# gcc library linking issue in Windows after cygwin installation

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cygwin

```
C:\slite\1.1>gcc -c ".\src\SDR.c" -o ".\obj\SDR.o" -I".\inc"  
C:\slite\1.1>gcc ".\obj\SDR.o" -o ".\exe\SDR.exe" -L".\lib" -lsres -lshis  
.\lib/sres.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could not compile C program using gcc after installing cygwin in Windows 2003.
Before installing cygwin, I was able to compile successfully.
I am compiling the code from Command prompt, not from cygwin terminal.
The gcc being used is from Dev-Cpp distribution.
Is the problem because of the directory separator ('/')  between the libraries directory specified by -L and individual libs specified by -l, being used by gcc after cygwin was installed?

If i try to compile in cygwin terminal I am getting unknown function calls error, though the functions are defined in the headers included.

EDIT:

```
C:\srmlite\x7.5.0.146-1600>where gcc
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\gcc.exe
```

The gcc was not from cygwin.
I have uninstalled cygwin and removed its directory too. I still see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the correct bin directory into the path in your Environment variables.
Something like this: **C:\soft\cygwin\bin**

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Cygwin modified the default environment, adding itself to `%PATH%`, so you're actually calling cygwin's gcc, check that out.

Comment: I had checked which gcc was being used using 'where'. Please see the EDIT.